# Regexp_replace separate words before and after OF excluding OFF

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a string I need to set space between words before and after OF.But if its OFF at the end then it should remain as is.Kindly correct my expression or if there is a better way to write.

```
PRINCEOFPERSIA ==> PRINCE OF PERSIA
PRINCOFFINLAND ==> PRINCE OF FINLAND
Blowoff ==> Blowoff
Spinoff ==> spinoff

I have written this exp.
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(spinoff,'(\w*)(off?)(.*)$','\1 \2 \3') from dual;
but it breaks it as 'spin off'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you want - replace only if there is at least 1 character after `of` other than `f`:

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(spinoff, '(\w+)(of)(f*[^f].*)$', '\1 \2 \3')
```

Comment: Cool!!! this is beautiful!!! yea it working perfectly now...its handling one more case OFFTRACK ==> OFFTRACK..Wow good..superb! You both( BTOUEG ) are genius

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work for me on regextester but don't understand why yet

Comment: what is regextester? also how do I get more expertise in it..is there some tool to help or its just pure logical thinking..

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you..I m heading home..its 7 30pm now..Thanks again

Comment: @deathApril Hello Sir,I have one more problem if there are two words like BLOWOFF DVD then the regexp doesn't work

Comment: this case is not specified in the question.. no idea how to handle this without lookarounds (they are not supported in Oracle i believe)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will either match "off" at the end of the sentence, or "of" anywhere.

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(spinoff,'(off$)|(of)','\1 \2 ') form dual;
```

This alternative tries to make sure you do not add a trailing space if the word ends by "of":

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(spinoff,'(off$)|(of)([^$])','\1 \2 \3') form dual;
```

Comment: I have Oracle 11g R1.I don't think ! is a part of regexp

Comment: no lookarounds in oracle SQL (or other POSIX-based regex implementations), i'm affraid

Comment: too bad, let's find another solution then

Comment: Yes it does not fulfill other criteria..PRINCEOFPERSIA.Also if its PRINCEOFFALKLAND it should become PRINCE OF FALKLAND

Comment: I am ok with spaces before and after I will trim it at the end.

Comment: Btoueg you are almost 90% fulfilling my requirements..but princeoffalkland is not satisfying the expression

Comment: The solution is now 95% :)

Comment: Its actually 100%..woww..ur awesome man!!cool very nice..Thanks a lot...:-)

Comment: Beware as it may add trailing spaces to Blowoff or Spinoff. I haven't tested all the cases.

Comment: @btoueg,I have one more problem if there are two words like BLOWOFF DVD then the regexp doesn't work.